# Transform a python nested list into an HTML table

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, nested-lists

I want to transform a list of rows in Python into an HTML table to ultimately send in an email body. Let's say my list of rows is stored as the variable `req_list` (representing the import data from a .csv file, for example) looks like:

```
> [['Email', 'Name', 'Name ID', 'Policy ID',
> 'Policy Number', 'Policy Effective Date'],
>  ['me@gmail.com','My Name', 
  '5700023153486', '57000255465455','C4545647216', '1/1/2017']]
```

Please ignore the above `>` formatting that appears incorrect.

You can probably guess that the first row in the list contains column headers. I want to generate an HTML table out of this list. Assume for this example that there could be **any number of additional rows to add to the table**, but no need to teach me about looping to handle this or error handling if there are 0.

How can I change this into an HTML table formatted relatively well? (e.g. black and white, with gridlines perhaps). I do not know HTML very well and have tried the following:

```
for thing in req_list:
    for cell in thing:
        req_tbl = req_tbl + "<tr><td>" + str(cell)
```

Which yields basically each "cell" in the list printed one after another on a single line, when read in my email inbox (the code sends this `req_table` variable to myself in an email)

```
Email
Name
Name ID
Policy ID
```

and so on.

How can I get this formatted into a proper HTML table? Furthermore, is there a way I can read the "html" text contained in `req_table` within python so I can check my work? I have used urllib to open pages/files but can't seem to pass it a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Pandas for that, only two lines of code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(req_list[1:], columns=req_list[0])
df.to_html()

'<table border="1" class="dataframe">\n  <thead>\n    <tr style="text-align: right;">\n      <th></th>\n      <th>Email</th>\n      <th>Name</th>\n      <th>Name ID</th>\n      <th>Policy ID</th>\n      <th>Policy Number</th>\n      <th>Policy Effective Date</th>\n    </tr>\n  </thead>\n  <tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <th>0</th>\n      <td>me@gmail.com</td>\n      <td>My Name</td>\n      <td>5700023153486</td>\n      <td>57000255465455</td>\n      <td>C4545647216</td>\n      <td>1/1/2017</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>\n</table>'
```

You can also read a html table into a DataFrame using:

```
df = pd.read_html(req_table)
```

Comment: Gosh I love python. Thanks!

Comment: np, glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use string formatting:

```
d = [['Email', 'Name', 'Name ID', 'Policy ID', 'Policy Number', 'Policy Effective Date'], ['me@gmail.com','My Name', '5700023153486', '57000255465455','C4545647216', '1/1/2017']]
final_table = "<table>\n<tr>{}</tr>\n{}</table>".format('\n'.join('<th>{}</th>'.format(i) for i in d[0]), '<tr>{}</tr>'.format('\n'.join('\n'.join(['<td>{}</td>'.format(b) for b in i]) for i in d[1:])))
```

When storing the HTML in a file and opening in a browser, the output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate) for this

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
t = [
    ["Email", "Name", "Name ID", "Policy ID", "Policy Number", "Policy Effective Date"],
    [
        "me@gmail.com",
        "My Name",
        "5700023153486",
        "57000255465455",
        "C4545647216",
        "1/1/2017",
    ],
]

print(tabulate(t, headers="firstrow", tablefmt="html"))
```

[image]